# Get all child nodes from table

Tags: sql, parent-child

I am trying to get all child nodes from a table, but my query is picking up some extra results and I'm not sure why

```
SELECT [pkID]
    ,[parentID]
    ,[CategoryName]
FROM [tblCategory]
WHERE [pkID] = 6
UNION ALL
SELECT [Sub].[pkID]
    ,[Sub].[ParentID]
    ,[Sub].[CategoryName]
FROM [tblCategory] [Sub]
INNER JOIN [tblCategory] AS [Sub2] ON [Sub].[ParentID] = [Sub2].[pkID]
```

I am getting other child nodes when running this query
Note* In my VB.Net application (Where this SQL needs to be called) ParentID of 0 is a root node in the treeview.

Table

```
pkID | ParentID | CategoryName
1    | 6        | Category1
2    | 0        | Category2
3    | 0        | Category3
4    | 0        | Category4
5    | 0        | Category5
6    | 0        | Category6
7    | 0        | Category7
8    | 0        | Category8
9    | 7        | Category9
```

Results

```
pkID | parentID | CategoryName
6    | 0        | Category6
1    | 6        | Category1
9    | 7        | Category9 <-- not a child of pkID=6
```

Comment: Is that the current result or the wanted result? (specify both)

Comment: Is this a recursive CTE? because looks like you miss the CTE

Comment: With your edit, you need the recursive cte and to anchor appropriately I will change.

Comment: Maybe you should make your example bigger. do you need first childs of 6 .... every node related to 6 or every ending leaf starting with 6.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is because you need the same where statement on the bottom select for `tblcategory` `WHERE [pkID] = 6`.  With out it you are getting the children of the entire table.

So something like this should work:

```
SELECT [pkID]
    ,[parentID]
    ,[CategoryName]
FROM [tblCategory]
WHERE [pkID] = 6
UNION ALL
SELECT [Sub].[pkID]
    ,[Sub].[ParentID]
    ,[Sub].[CategoryName]
FROM [tblCategory] [Sub]
INNER JOIN [tblCategory] AS [Sub2] ON [Sub].[ParentID] = [Sub2].[pkID]
WHERE [sub].[pkID] = 6
```

Simplified as Juan noted and I should have thought of can be done as a single where condition on the same select statement.

```
SELECT [pkID]
    ,[parentID]
    ,[CategoryName]
FROM [tblCategory]
WHERE [pkID] = 6
     or ParentId = 6
```

Here is a recursive cte method to get all of the children, grand children, great grand children, etc. of a parentid.

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT [pkID]
       ,[parentID]
       ,[CategoryName]
       -- ,1 AS [Level]
    FROM [tblCategory]
    WHERE [pkID] = 6


    UNION ALL

    SELECT
       t.pkId
       ,t.[parentID]
       ,t.CategoryName
       -- ,[Level] + 1 AS [Level]
    FROM
       [tblCategory] t
       INNER JOIN cte c
       ON t.ParentId = c.pkId
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
```

Comment: I've tried to use Level before, but it says that it is an invalid column name in ssms

Comment: what version of sql-server are you running?  Anyway if you change the column alias to something else or just bracket it it will work for you.

Comment: Since the question does not specify the database see link to table of databases that accept CTE https://www.sql-workbench.eu/dbms_comparison.html . Also maybe some database may need the expression "with recursive" instead of just "with"

Answer (score 3):

Supposing that the second node might have childs as well, I'd suggest a recursive query. Something like this (untested):

```
DECLARE @SearchID int = 6;

WITH cteTree AS(
SELECT pkID, parentID, CategoryName
  FROM tblCategory
  WHERE pkID = @SearchID
UNION ALL
SELECT pt.pkID, pt.parentID, pt.CategoryName
  FROM tblCategory AS pt
  JOIN cteTree AS ct ON ct.pkID = pt.parentID
)
SELECT *
  FROM cteTree
```

Comment: the recursive cte was already part of my answer about 10 minutes before you posted this did I miss something?

Comment: Sorry about that! It wasn't displayed when I stumbled about the question. I then typed my answer, had to correct the formatting and so on and when I committed my Answer, yours was displayed... guess I was too slow. Again: sorry! Had no intention to re-answer with a already provided idea.

Comment: No worries great minds think alike.  It is crazy how fast some answers get posted on here.

Answer (score 1):

Look like you try to make a recursive cte, but then you change your mind.

That query can be simplify like

```
SELECT [pkID]
    ,[parentID]
    ,[CategoryName]
FROM [tblCategory]
WHERE [pkID] = 6
   OR [ParentID] = 6
```

Comment: yep I should have looked at it a little more indepth to fix correctly rather than just make a minor change to his statement that I knew would work.  Good catch up vote to you.

Comment: Yes, I saw the missing CTE but wasnt sure what OP want.